# Get result of last six months using DATEDIFF

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to create a query in SQL that retrieves rows based on their date.

I want to get the result of the last 6 months using `DATEDIFF()` function (and not another function ) but my query still returns rows that are greater than `GETUTCDATE()`.

The query that I use is:

```
SELECT * FROM CARS
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) < 180
```

Why am i still getting results that are greater than `GETUTCDATE()` ?

Comment: Do you want last 6 months to the day, or from the start of the month?

Comment: last 6 months to the day

Comment: Because if `ExpiredWarranty > GETUTCDATE()` then `DATEDIFF` between them returns a negative number which is definitely less then 180. Try `WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) < 180 AND DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) >= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if `ExpiredWarranty > GETUTCDATE()` then `DATEDIFF` between them returns a negative number which is definitely less then 180.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) < 180
  AND DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) >= 0;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 180;
```

Answer (score 3):

`DATEDIFF` returns a *positive* number whenever the third argument is *greater* than the second.  In your case, you want records whose warranties have expired within 6 months.  On one extreme, this is 180 days, and the other extreme, this is 0 days.  For warranties expiring in the *future*, your current call to `DATEDIFF` would return a *negative* number.

To fix this, just restrict the `DATEDIFF` output to between 0 and 180 days, and don't allow negative diffs:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 180;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you may think you want to use `datediff`, but the fact that you are using it (or any other function, for that matter) on a column makes it impossible for SQL Server to use any indexes defined with this column - and that might be a real performance penalty for that.

Second, the reason you get records for future dates is that if the first date is later than the second date, the `DateDiff` function will return a negative number. All negative numbers I know of are smaller than 180.

A better query would be this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CARS
WHERE c.ExpiredWarranty <= GETUTCDATE()
-- If you want 6 months, don't bother with days...
AND c.ExpiredWarranty > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

- Try this:

  `WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) < 180`
- Or:

  `WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.ExpiredWarranty, GETUTCDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 180;`